# Creating a file in a non-existing folder using OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, file, opencv, directory

i am trying to create an image file using opencv in python.
when i am creating it in same folder file is created

```
          face_file_name = "te.jpg"
          cv2.imwrite(face_file_name, image)
```

but when i am trying to create it in another folder like

```
          face_file_name = "test\te.jpg"
          cv2.imwrite(face_file_name, image)
```

file is not created. can someone explain the reasons??

i even tried giving absolute path.
i am using python2.7 in windows.

Comment: What about [escape characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)? What if you tried `"test\\te.jpg"`?

Comment: thanq chrisaycock forgot abt that

Comment: and its only creating if folder already exits wht if i want to create a new folder and create the file in it

Comment: any errors? do you have write access to the folder?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`cv2.imwrite()` will not write an image in another directory if the directory does not exist. You first need to create the directory before attempting to write to it:

```
import os
dirname = 'test'
os.mkdir(dirname)
```

From here, you can either write to the directory without changing your working directory:

```
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(dirname, face_file_name), image)
```

Or change your working directory and omit the directory prefix, depending on your needs:

```
os.chdir(dirname)
cv2.imwrite(face_file_name, image)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Took me a long time before I realised I had to create the folder, couldn't figure out why my images wouldn't be saved :/